# How to shows a sum of number with moving ratio?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, recursion

I have a homework that got me confused. It requires us to make a program which given an input should calculate 100 + (50*1) and show 150 on the console.

Given an input of 3, the output should be: [100 + (50*0)] + [100 + 50*1] + [100 + 50*2] = 450, and it should show 450 on the console.

I expected the output to be `450`  (from 100*3 + (50*0 + 50*1 + 50*2)), but the actual output is `200`. How can I solve my problem?

```
int N,punch,bonus;
scanf("%d",&N); getchar();


for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    bonus = 50*i;
    punch = 100 + bonus;
}
printf("%d\n",punch);
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: Your loop is *overwriting* the previous results.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Initialize your accumulator variable before the loop.
2. Don't overwrite the previous value in the loop (using `=`), but rather, increment it (using `+=` or just summing the variable on the other side of the assignment too).

Correct code would be:

```
int N, punch, bonus;
scanf("%d", &N);
getchar();

punch = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    bonus = 50*i;
    punch = punch + 100 + bonus;
}

printf("%d\n", punch);
getchar();

return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize both `punch` and `bonus` to 0.

Change this line:
`punch = 100 + bonus;`

to this:
`punch += 100 + bonus;`

Your loop was overwriting the value of `punch` every time it ran. Hence the mistake.
An input of three would return 100 + 50*2 that is 200.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the variable punch is not initialized.

```
int N,punch,bonus;
      ^^^^^
```

You should initially initialize it to 100.

```
int N,punch = 100,bonus;
```

Otherwise if the user enter 0 then the result will be an indeterminate value.

Within the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    bonus = 50*i;
    punch = 100 + bonus;
}
```

instead of to accumulate values of the sequence you are reassigning the variable punch

```
    punch = 100 + bonus;
```

You should write

```
punch += 100 + bonus;
```

Usually such assignments are given to learn the recursion. A recursive function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int sum_of_seria( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned long long int initial = 100;
    return n == 0 ? initial : initial + 50 * n + sum_of_seria( n - 1 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    printf( "%llu\n", sum_of_seria( n ) );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter `2` then the output will be

```
450
```

A non-recursive program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int Initial = 100;

    unsigned int n = 0;
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    unsigned long long punch = Initial;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        punch += Initial + 50llu * ( i + 1 );
    }

    printf( "%llu\n", punch );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

In fact the loop is redundant. You could write simply

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int Initial = 100;

    unsigned int n = 0;
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    unsigned long long punch = Initial * ( n + 1 ) + 50llu * n * ( n + 1 ) / 2 ;

    printf( "%llu\n", punch );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I give you the answer I will explaint what mistake that you did in this programe.

- we assume your `input number = 3`

  **1.** In `for` loop when `i = 0`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        bonus = 50 * i; 
        // i = 0
        //then bonus = 0

        punch = 100 + bonus; 
        //punch = 100 + 0
        //punch = 100
}
```

Then you can see your punch value is equal to 100

**2.** after first loop you `i` value will be `i = 1`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        bonus = 50 * i; 
        // i = 1
        //then bonus = 50

        punch = 100 + bonus; 
        //punch = 100 + 50
        //punch = 150
}
```

Now your new `punch` value is `150` but according to your equation

```
[100 + 50 * 0] + [100 + 50 * 1] = 100 + 150 = 250
```

Acording to your programe it shows

```
first iterate : punch = 100
second iterate: punch = 150 //but this should be 250
...
...
```

Then you need to devalop this program into

```
first iterate : punch = 100
second iterate: punch = 250 //like this
....
....
```

Then we can try this **option**

```
punch = punch + 100 + bonus;
```

according to this

```
first iterate : punch = 0 + 100 + 0
                punch = 100

second iterate: punch = 100 + 100 + 50
                punch = 250
```

Hope this explain will give you some idea. Hear are some **solutions**

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        bonus = 50 * i;
        bonus = bonus + 100;

        punch = punch + bonus;
}
```

**or**

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        bonus = 50 * i;
        punch = punch + 100 + bonus;
}
```